# For C/C++ syntax highlighting in vscode : how to tell vscode that a compile option "-Dxxxx" will be used?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, define-syntax

When developing for micro controller, we use a lot of compile-time defines passed to the compiler with the "-Dxxxx" syntax.
I would like to configure vscode such that it knows that certain defines will be provided and such that it highlights code properly corresponding to those info.

How would I do that ?

Comment: Could be a better way today, but here is an older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415076/how-can-i-define-macros-for-the-c-intellisense-engine

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) installed.

**1** - Open Command Palette by Ctrl + Shift + P or View -> Command Palette...
**2** - Select `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)` 
**3** - Scroll down to `Defines` section, where you can add your defines/macros.

Also, In this tab you can tell vscode about your compiler options such as, the compiler arguments, the language standard you are using, include paths, etc.

Comment: Works very well !

Comment: I have seen that everything is stored in a c_cpp_properties.json file under the .vscode folder under the configurations > defines fields.